# Is there a jQuery plugin that will let me cross fade 2 images on click?

Tags: jquery, image-manipulation

I don't want to use the Cycle plugin as it doesn't seem to bind to click easily. I want to be able to click an image and have it change to another image via cross fade.

Comment: you could use [CSS3](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

Comment: That's incredible! How would I retain the second image on click?

Comment: What do you mean? Is that not what demo 2 does?

Comment: touché. answer and i'll accept

Comment: Are you going to be okay with the fact that this does not work at all in IE?

Comment: Crap - I'd rather something that works with IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use CSS3 and jQuery like in this [tutorial](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) :)